# Match documents in elasticsearch with AND and OR on different fields

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

I am new to elastic search and I am working with MySQL and MongoDB. I want to write the query which gives products which are active and it's name or brand_name or model_number or category contains a specific word.

Here is MySQL query.
SELECT * FROM products WHERE active=0 AND (name LIKE '%car%' OR brand_name LIKE '%car%' OR model_number LIKE '%car%' OR category LIKE '%car%');

I already tried with the below query in elastic search, but it's just AND operator.

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"active": "1"}},
                {"regexp": {"name": "cars.*"}},
                {"regexp": {"brand_data.brand_name": "cars.*"}},
                {"regexp": {"model_number": "cars.*"}},
            ]
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me to write this query in elasticsearch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for a 'or' nested inside an 'and' clause. this is the correct format:

```
"query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {"match": {"active": "1"}},
                {"bool":{"should":[
                {"regexp": {"name": "cars.*"}},
                {"regexp": {"brand_data.brand_name": "cars.*"}},
                {"regexp": {"model_number": "cars.*"}}]}}
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Short answer - for OR you can use `should` occurrence of boolean query.

Long answer with example: 
It can be done in several ways, but I want point you to one detail. If you need to search only `active=1` or `active=0` results, it will be better to use `filter` occurrence in your query. It will give you better performance and caching.

> The clause (query) must appear in matching documents. However unlike must the score of the query will be ignored. Filter clauses are executed in filter context, meaning that scoring is ignored and clauses are considered for caching.

So I can propose you this query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "active": "1"
        }
      },
      "should": [
        {
          "regexp": {
            "name": "cars.*"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "brand_data.brand_name": "cars.*"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "model_number": "cars.*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not working. It's fetching all documents which are active. not applying should filter